# Windows のサウンドの「既定の形式」の項目をプログラム上から変更したい

Tags: windows, audio

Windows のサウンドの「既定の形式」の項目をプログラム上から変更したいです。
画像の赤く記した部分になります。

[image: オーディオプロパティ]

Core Audio APIs の IAudioClient::Initialize で新しいフォーマットに変更しようとしていました。
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudioclient-initialize

S_OK が返ってきて関数自体は正しく呼べたようなのですが、フォーマットは変更されませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

サードパーティ製のコマンドラインツールを使用可能であれば、[SoundVolumeView.exe](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html)で変更可能です。

```
.\SoundVolumeView.exe /SetDefaultFormat "スピーカー" 24 96000
```

Windows11のPowershellで上記コマンドを実行し、`スピーカー`デバイスの既定の形式が24ビット、48000Hzになることを確認しました。

**参考資料**

- [Change Soundcard Bit Depth and Sample Rate via Command Line in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1701907)